# How to setup auto-refresh in PowerBI, when encountering cyclic reference error bug?

Tags: powerbi

Whenever new data is loaded and I attempt refreshing the PowerBI report, I run into the error "A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation in Power BI." The error then no longer appears once I try refreshing again, and everything is copacetic.

Here is another SO post describing my situation: [A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation in Power BI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75079083/a-cyclic-reference-was-encountered-during-evaluation-in-power-bi)

It seems that this error is a bug.

I need to have the refresh on this PowerBI report be automated. Thus, I need to have some way where I refresh the report twice. I could simply set a refresh schedule so that the 2nd refresh is 30 minutes after the 1st refresh, but PowerBI completely deactivates the scheduled refresh if it runs into errors enough times (only a handful). Which would mean that I would have to re-introduce a new scheduled refresh every couple of days, which is not ideal.

Is there a workaround for this? Maybe some way I can refresh the report through Python or R?